# How to calculate SPEI for india using netcdf datasets and spei package of python?

Tags: python

I have downloaded imd yearly rainfall data, min temperature data and max temperature data of 1.0*1.0 resolution in NetCDF format from 2007 to 2018, and saved to a folder in my local drive. Directory path: `"E:\\Lipsa(MTech)\\Final year project\\dataset\\imd gridded"`, folder names:`"rain_netcdf"`, `"max_temp_netcdf"`, `"min_temp_netcdf"`, files names: `"2007_rain.nc"`,`"2008_rain.nc"`, and so on, `"2007_tmax.nc"`, `"2008_tmax.nc"`, and so on, and `"2007_tmin.nc"`, `"2008_tmin.nc"` and so on respectively. I also have the shapefile of india saved in directory: `"E:\\Lipsa_data\\India_studyarea"`, with file names as: `"India_Boundary.shp"`, `"India_Boundary.prj"` and other.

Now how can I use these data to calculate spei-1, spei-3, spei-6 and spei-12 for india using spei 0.3.3 package using python in spyder and save the spei values as both .csv and .nc format.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
from spei import spei
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import shapefile as shp

os.chdir("E:\\Lipsa(MTech)\\Final year project\\dataset\\imd gridded")

rain_path = "rain_netcdf"
max_temp_path = "max_temp_netcdf"
min_temp_path = "min_temp_netcdf"
india_shape_path = "E:\\Lipsa_data\\India_studyarea\\India_Boundary.shp"

sf = shp.Reader(india_shape_path)

# Extract the boundary coordinates
shapes = sf.shapes()
boundary = shapes[0].bbox
min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = boundary

# Define the coordinates for India
lon = np.arange(min_lon, max_lon + 1.0, 1.0)
lat = np.arange(max_lat, min_lat - 1.0, -1.0)


periods = [1, 2, 3, 6, 12] # Time periods for SPEI calculation

for year in range(2007, 2019):
    # Load the rainfall data
    rain_file = os.path.join(rain_path, str(year) + "_rain.nc")
    rain_data = Dataset(rain_file)
    rain = rain_data.variables['RAINFALL'][:]

    # Load the maximum temperature data
    max_temp_file = os.path.join(max_temp_path, str(year) + "_tmax.nc")
    max_temp_data = Dataset(max_temp_file)
    max_temp = max_temp_data.variables['tmax'][:]

    # Load the minimum temperature data
    min_temp_file = os.path.join(min_temp_path, str(year) + "_tmin.nc")
    min_temp_data = Dataset(min_temp_file)
    min_temp = min_temp_data.variables['tmin'][:]

    # Calculate the SPEI for each time period
    for p in periods:
        spei_values = spei(rain=rain, tmax=max_temp, tmin=min_temp, time_dim=None, 
        calibration_year_initial= None, calibration_year_final= None, fitting_params=None, 
        periodicity='monthly', distribution='Gamma', verbose=False)

        # Save the SPEI values as a CSV file
        spei_df = pd.DataFrame(spei_values, columns=['SPEI'])
        spei_df.to_csv(f'SPEI_{p}_{year}.csv', index=False)

        # Save the SPEI values as a netCDF file
        ds = xr.Dataset({'SPEI': (('lat', 'lon'), spei_values)},
                        coords={'lon': lon, 'lat': lat})
        ds.to_netcdf(f'SPEI_{p}_{year}.nc')
```

```
spei_values = spei(rain=rain, tmax=max_temp, tmin=min_temp, time_dim=None, calibration_year_initial= None, calibration_year_final= None, fitting_params=None, periodicity='monthly', distribution='Gamma', verbose=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[7], line 1
spei_values = spei(rain=rain, tmax=max_temp, tmin=min_temp, time_dim=None, calibration_year_initial= None, calibration_year_final= None, fitting_params=None, periodicity='monthly', distribution='Gamma', verbose=False)

TypeError: spei() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rain'
```

Can someone help me with the correct code for this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the function's documentation?

```
"""Method to compute the Standardized Precipitation Evaporation Index
[spei_2010]_.
Parameters
----------
series: pandas.Series
    Pandas time series of the precipitation. Time series index
    should be a pandas DatetimeIndex.
dist: scipy.stats.rv_continuous
    Can be any continuous distribution from the scipy.stats library.
    However, for the SPEI generally the log-logistic (fisk) probability
    density function is recommended. Other appropriate choices could be
    the lognormal or PearsonIII distribution.
Returns
-------
pandas.Series
References
----------
.. [spei_2010] Vicente-Serrano S.M., Beguería S., López-Moreno J.I.:
   A Multi-scalar drought index sensitive to global warming: The
   Standardized Precipitation Evapotranspiration Index.
   Journal of Climate, 23, 1696-1718, 2010.
"""
```

The error message is clear: 'rain' is not an argument, 'series', and 'dist' are. Looks like this SPI function is for weather stations while you are using gridded data. I suspect you called the wrong library

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.